# C program to count number of lines in a file

Tags: c, file

Very simple code, works fine. I'm mainly interested in the method I used to count lines. I thought about using fgetc, but I'm not even sure if it'd read the newline character, and I think it's slower too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 1000

int main(void){
    FILE *in_file;
    char line[MAX_SIZE];

    in_file = fopen("test", "r");
    if(in_file == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int counter = 0; /*Number of lines*/

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), in_file) != NULL){
        counter++;
    }

    printf("Number of lines in the file is %i", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you say, it works fine.  But I can nitpick.

The main flaw is that you could get a wrong count if any line is longer than 999 bytes.  (In general, you should stress-test your code by cranking down the buffer size to ridiculously small numbers and checking whether you obtain the same results.)

The performance could be improved.  Since `fgets()` has no way of knowing in advance where the newlines occur, it must read the file contents into a temporary buffer (which is invisible to you), then copy each line into the `line` buffer.  Since only care about counting `'\n'` characters, you could read fixed-size blocks to avoid this internal copying.

It's awkward to read 1000 bytes at a time.  You would be better off reading chunks that are aligned with the blocks on the disk.  A better choice would be 1024.

You could use the `perror()` function to report why I/O operations failed.  Technically, `fgets()` could fail too, so you should check for that.

It's a good habit to ensure that your `fopen()` is paired with `fclose()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 1024

int main(void) {
    const char filename[] = "test";
    FILE *in_file;
    char buffer[SIZE + 1], lastchar = '\n';
    size_t bytes;
    int lines = 0;

    if (NULL == (in_file = fopen(filename, "r"))) {
        perror(filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer) - 1, in_file))) {
        lastchar = buffer[bytes - 1];
        for (char *c = buffer; (c = memchr(c, '\n', bytes - (c - buffer))); c++) {
            lines++;
        }
    }
    if (lastchar != '\n') {
        lines++;  /* Count the last line even if it lacks a newline */
    }
    if (ferror(in_file)) {
        perror(filename);
        fclose(in_file);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fclose(in_file);
    printf("Number of lines in the file is %i\n", lines);
}
```

The `for` loop above is a bit tricky for beginners, but should be acceptable for experienced C programmers.  The loop

> ```
> for (char *c = buffer; (c = memchr(c, '\n', bytes - (c - buffer))); c++)
> ```

means:

- Search for the next newline, starting from the pointer `c`, in the remaining `bytes - (c - buffer)` bytes that have been read but not examined yet.
- If a newline is found, make `c` point to the position just after it.
- If no newline is found, then we're done with this chunk.  Try reading more input then.

The extra set of parentheses around `c = memchr(…)` is an indication to the compiler and to other programmers that the `=` is indeed intentional, and is not supposed to be `==`.

Comment: Should file "test" contain null characters, this will cause `strchr()` to miss the true end of the line.  Recommend to use `memchr()` instead of `strchr()` - might be faster too.

Comment: +1 because I would have never had the idea to check for null pointers in such an elegant way as this line `for (char *c = buffer; (c = strchr(c, '\n')); c++)`. Is this good practise though? I was confused at first because I didn't expect an assignment in the part where you usually just check a condition - or is this something you'd want to drop for clarity reasons?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think I entirely understand what you did. I have no issues up until to while loop.

Starting from the loop:

As long as EOF hasn't been reached:
Add a null character (to make it a null terminated string?)
Set lastchar to the character before \0, which should be \n until the last line.

In the for loop:
Create a char pointer, starting from element 0, then reset the pointer to the location of the \n character, which causes the loop to only perform its block once.

Also, doesn't this still read the entire file into the array buffer?

Answer (score 1):

`fgetc()` does read newline characters. It would be a pretty useless function if it didn't!

If you benchmark versions of the code using `fgetc()` and `fgets()`, quite likely you will see no measurable difference. (Do this on a fairly big text file - e.g. 100Mb, and make sure you run both programs several times, otherwise the results will depend mostly on how your operating system caches the file in memory when you read it, not on your code!).

Both `fgets()` and `fgetc()` will read the file one buffer at a time, and (with luck) the buffer size will be the optimum for the file system you are reading, not a guessed number like 1000 or 1024.

In fact, if you switch on compiler optimization, `fgetc()` is likely to be *in-line* code which usually amounts to no more than the single expression `*bufptr++`, where `bufptr` is a pointer into the operating system's file buffer.

This type of code is often a good illustration of the principle that "premature optimization without benchmarking is the root of all evil". Use the library routines that allows the simplest logic, not the one that you *guessed* might run fastest.